# BroadcastReceiver does not receive anything

Tags: android, kotlin, broadcastreceiver

I am using a broadcast receiver to exchange data between a service and the MainActivity, but the receiver doesn't receive anything. Does anyone know what's the problem here?

Receiver code:

```
 private var broadcastReceiver =  object : BroadcastReceiver() {
        override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
            val extras = intent.extras
            if(extras != null){
                when(extras.getString("message")){
                    "lock_phone" -> devicePolicyManager.lockNow()
                    "block_touch" -> devicePolicyManager.setKeyguardDisabled(adminComponent,true)
                    "unblock_touch" -> devicePolicyManager.setKeyguardDisabled(adminComponent,false)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Sender code:

```
class WatchService : WearableListenerService() {
    override fun onMessageReceived(messageEvent: MessageEvent) {
        if (messageEvent.path == "/command") {
            val message = String(messageEvent.data)
            val messageIntent = Intent()
            messageIntent.action = Intent.ACTION_SEND
            messageIntent.putExtra("message", message)
            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(messageIntent)
        } else {
            super.onMessageReceived(messageEvent)
        }
    }
}
```

Edit:
I register the receiver in onCreate using

```
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, IntentFilter())
```

Thank you for helping me!

Comment: So where do you call `registerReceiver`?

Comment: @ianhanniballake In onCreate: 
`LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, IntentFilter())`

Answer (score 1):

You've registered your `BroadcastReceiver` with an empty `IntentFilter`.

When you register your `BroadcastReceiver`, you need to provide an `IntentFilter` that tells Android what broadcast `Intent`s should be delivered to your `BroadcastReceiver`. Since your `Service` is sending a broadcast `Intent` with ACTION_SEND, you can set up an `IntentFilter` that will trigger on `ACTION_SEND`, like this:

```
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this)
    .registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SEND))
```